# PHP: Can anonymous functions inside an associative array access other members of the array?

Tags: php, associative-array

In the following example, is it possible to access the 'str' value from within the anonymous function?

```
$foo = array(
  'str' => 'THIS IS A STRING',
  'fn' => function () {
    // is it possible from within here to access 'str'?
  }
);
```

Comment: Can't you just access `$foo['str']` directly? (I don't have a closure-enabled version of PHP to test right now)

Comment: No, `$foo` is undefined.

Comment: ...it *is* possible to access `$foo['str']` directly, see my solution below:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `$foo` is defined in the global namespace you should be able to access it via `$GLOBALS['foo']['str']` (or make it available via the `global $foo;` construct). If it isn't (local var, parameter, member variable, …), you have to pass it (as reference!) to the anonymous function:

```
$foo = array(
  'str' => 'THIS IS A STRING',
  'fn' => function () use(&$foo) {
    echo $foo['str'];
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I am able to access it by `$GLOBALS['foo']['str']`

Comment: Be aware that you cannot access it via the `$GLOBAL` array, if it's a local or a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a different way to do this without using global variables:

```
<?php

    $arr = array("a" => 12,
                "b" => function($num)
                        {
                            $c = $num * 2;
                            return $c;
                        });

    echo $arr["b"]($arr["a"]);
?>
```

*Note the weird syntax of ending the array index call with method parentheses*. By passing `$arr["a"]` as a parameter you can have access to that value (I imagine you could pass by reference as well).
If you were **not** to pass anything into the anonymous function, you would call it like this:

```
$arr["b"]();
```

If you don't include the method parentheses it won't work.